# Some friends say Combinate(to mix something). Isn't this wrong? I think the right one is Combine? I'm so confused. Thanks

Tags: grammar, verbs

Some friends say Combinate(to mix something) is grammarly correct. Isn't this wrong? I think the right one is Combine? I'm so confused.
Some say i'm wrong with combine, they say the correct one is combinate because it is the opposite of Separate. One more question, If combine is correct, then why separate ends with ate?
They are the opposite of each other. Thanks, sorry for my English

Comment: The full OED says the verb usage is ***Obsolete. rare***

Comment: Have you done a search for "combinate" in a dictionary.  That should quickly confirm that "combine" is standard word in English, and "combinate" isn't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers true, but if they are considering it as an antonym to 'separate' then they are looking to use it as a verb, not a noun.

Comment: @JamesK I was surprised to find that 'combinate' **is** in Websters.

Comment: I've never heard a native speaker say "combinate". When my ESL students say "combinate", I correct them to "combine".

Answer (score 3):

The word 'combinate' does not appear in the Cambridge dictionary, and as a British English speaker, it sounds wrong to me. It is not a [conjugation](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-combine.html) of the verb *to combine*.

However, I was very surprised to find it **is** in [Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/combinate) dictionary, so it may have had some limited use in American English, but [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=combine%2Ccombinate%2Ccombining%2Ccombination&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) shows that its use in literature is almost non-existent, and some of those examples seem to be as a noun.

The logic that you cited about it being the opposite of separate is nonsense - antonyms don't necessarily have the same etymology. Further, 'separate' and 'combine' both have many synonyms. You might as well ask why 'blend' and 'divide' do not end the same way.

I would advise against using it. I think people that use it instead of 'combine' are probably confused about the word 'combination', which is a noun (the name of the combining process, or of the result of it).

Comment: There is a famous tech company called **Y Combinator**, presumably named after the "Y combinator" function in [**combinatory logic**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic)